# Discord bot playing a game

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I have recently created a discord bot with the `"playing a game"` status and there is the code that I have set:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is online!');
    bot.user.setActivity('osu!');
```

The problem is that it can't add an icon or whatever it called with only the name of the game that I wanted to show

[image]

I watched some old tutorials and explaining the same thing but `bot.user.setGame(' ');` instead of `bot.user.setActivity(' ')` and it shows this on those videos:

[image]

At least with an icon on it.

Is there any way I can add an icon of my choice or only the mark interrogation one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, in discord.js V12 you cannot set a game icon for your bot. There may be third party apps or libraries that allow you to do so but nothing that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

for v13 its

```
client.user.setActivity('<the game you want the bot to play>')
```